# What is the best practice to save space when using docker for CI/CD?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, circleci

I am using CircleCI and docker for CI/CD pipeline. Basically, I wrap up the (python) app and the environment in a new docker image every time I push new code to GitHub. Then I push the image to my private Docker registry hosted with Nexus and deploy my app by pulling the latest image from this registry and run container.

My problem is that these docker images are taking tons of space:

```
    REPOSITORY                       TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
my-app   0.1.23              6f13476770c2        3 minutes ago       1.99GB
my-app   0.1.22              7ff62dddb50a        10 minutes ago      1.99GB
my-app   0.1.21              55af2d3235c7        3 hours ago         1.99GB
my-app   0.1.20              304543b7fc71        5 hours ago         1.99GB
my-app   0.1.17              fddcef3f262b        2 weeks ago         1.99GB
my-app   0.1.16              a62c9ba1f997        2 weeks ago         1.99GB
my-app   0.1.12              a8d87d86699a        2 weeks ago         1.99GB
```

Since the running environment takes a lot of space in the image and it does not change frequently (not as frequently as changing code), I assume lots of space is just wasted by building the same dependencies/environment over and over again. So the question is am I doing it the right way? If not what is the best practice. Thanks in advance!

P.S. The environment I am using requires some dependencies (numpy, tensorflow etc.) which need GCC, therefore I am not able not to use python alpine image if I am not mistaken.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch
# Install app dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip

RUN mkdir /opt/working_dir/
WORKDIR /opt/working_dir/

# Copy the entire project into the current directory
COPY . ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Some docker image histories:

```
$ docker image history my-app:0.1.23
6f13476770c2        19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt      955MB               
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip            4.97MB              
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:5bb6533618d16964c…   16.5MB              
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /opt/reco_engine/     0B                  
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir /opt/reco_engine/              0B                  
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   90.6MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;   wget -O get-pip.py 'ht…   6.04MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=19…   0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/bin  && ln -s idle3…   32B                 
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex   && wget -O python.tar.x…   65.3MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.8     0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E…   0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   16.9MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/…   0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   562MB               
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   142MB               
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   7.81MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   23.2MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:843b8a2a9df1a0730…   101MB 

$ docker image history my-app:0.1.22
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
7ff62dddb50a        19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt      955MB               
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c pip install --upgrade pip            4.97MB              
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:f054e43f5766a4738…   16.5MB              
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop) WORKDIR /opt/reco_engine/     0B                  
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c mkdir /opt/reco_engine/              0B                  
<missing>           19 hours ago        /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   90.6MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;   wget -O get-pip.py 'ht…   6.04MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=19…   0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/bin  && ln -s idle3…   32B                 
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex   && wget -O python.tar.x…   65.3MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.8     0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GPG_KEY=0D96DF4D4110E…   0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   16.9MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/…   0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;  apt-get update;  apt-ge…   562MB               
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   142MB               
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c set -ex;  if ! command -v gpg > /…   7.81MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install…   23.2MB              
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                 0B                  
<missing>           6 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:843b8a2a9df1a0730…   101MB
```

Comment: The size calculation there includes layers that may be shared with multiple images. Can you include your Dockerfile for your project? A `docker history` for several of these images would also be useful.

Comment: @BMitch Thx for the reply! Dockerfile included. I noticed that indeed those images have multiple layers in common with the same hash value. However, with each new deployment I found that around 1GB is consumed, which I guess is far from optimal since there is only a few lines change in code.

Comment: It looks like `pip install -r requirements.txt` adds nearly a gigabyte onto your image size. How long does that step take? If it's not terribly long, you could make the entrypoint of the image be a bash script that installs the requirements before running, but if @squarism's solution will work for you, that's probably a better way to go about it.

Comment: @briman0094 My concern over installing requirements for each run is 1. yes it takes some time and 2. the app has dependencies on some packages hosted on PyPI, and if they would break someday I can still roll back and use the old images. But thx for the hint!

Comment: If that's the case, one optimization you can do off the bat is to copy `requirements.txt` *before* the rest of the files, then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`, and *then* copy everything else. This allows the requirements installation step to be cached (and reused) unless the `requirements.txt` file changes.

Comment: @briman0094 Wow! That's some neat trick I need to try. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Figure out what your apps have in common.  That becomes your baseline image for your app deploys.
2. Create a baseline image named after your company.  Call it `app-base`.
3. Every image is based off the app-base.  It does a build step that uses the base.  Look up multi-stage builds.
4. Your `app-base` image is absolutely as small as you can make it.  It does not include things that a VM does.  You start with a small base image and you work, work, work to make it very small.
5. Commits and deploys are small changes.  Your app builds rely on `app-base`.  Your app size depends but you shouldn't ship development tools.

I'm going to assume you run python.  For example, your images are 2GB.  The Alpine Linux Python docker image is 80MB.  Your app may add say, another 100MB.  If you have many native dependencies then it may be difficult to break it up or use Alpine (say you need GCC).

If everything is lucky, your app base image would be 80MB and the CI built app image you would deploy would be 100MB.  The 80MB would not be taken up over and over again because your Nexus server would reuse `app-base` that has Python in it (from Alpine Python or your own customizations).  Taking this approach might save you a lot of space (which translates to speed).

But it depends on your app and how legacy it is.

"Best" practices (there's no such thing but here's some tips):

- Use alpine linux images as a baseline if you can.  Trade off with GCC deps.
- Make your own tiny images for your company, customize if you need to.
- Add as little as you can.  If you need to compile something, add compile tools in as a stage and don't ship that.  You don't need it.
- In other words, use multi-stage builds
- Aim for small binaries if you can.  Can you compile to binary?  Huge savings.
- Try not to approach it like VMs.  ie: Don't install ssh.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed response! I googled multi-stage build and read some posts. If I am not mistaken, it can be used to selectively build development image (which includes all the building requirements) and production image (which only includes the compiled app). 

The problem with my app is I am deploying python scripts to production (I know it is probably not a good practice but I really struggled to compile python codes into binary). Therefore my dev environment is basically my production environment. I also found it difficult to install numpy and tensorflow under alpine.

Comment: It's tricky and yeah getting to binary is hard/weird for python.  Interpreted languages don't shrink easily (compared to say Go).  Use a base image with your requirements to reduce space on your CI server and in production.  Keep the base image up to date.  If your base image has no value/use, just use a community image.  I looked at the official tensorflow docker images and they seem to be 2GB.  You might be out of luck.

You should start `FROM tensorflow` and not python.  Or build your own base image.

Answer (score 2):

Most python Dockerfile examples out there handles the requirements.txt file separate from the rest of the python code, like:

```
FROM python:3.6-stretch
# Install app dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-dev \
    python3-pip

RUN mkdir /opt/working_dir/
WORKDIR /opt/working_dir/

# Copy the entire project into the current directory
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./
```

By doing this, your builds will be much faster and reuse all but the last layer unless the requirements.txt file gets updated. You'll still see large images in the `image ls` output, but if you inspect the layers, you'll see that almost every one of them is the same between all images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code example! @briman0094 mentioned the same idea. I am going to test it out :)

Comment: So we could run `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` not attached to  a`&&` command

Comment: Chaining a run command is useful when you want to reduce the number of layers, and needed when one command deletes or modifies files that were created by a previous command (you don't want layers with previous states of the file). The `pip install` is useful to be separate for layer caching.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to optimize your images. If you post your Dockerfile I can give you hints.

You can also inspect the history of an image:

```
docker image history my-app:0.1.23
```

This tells you how much space each command adds with the specific layer it builds.

Also you can inspect your images and see how many layers are used in common:

```
docker inspect my-app:0.1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `docker_layer_caching` to your config file:

```
jobs:
 jobName:
   machine:
     enabled: true
     docker_layer_caching: true
```

After this, all old layers are cached on CircleCI.

Comment: I've done this already but thx for pointing it out! The problem I am having is the builds are consuming too much space with new images in my private registry and the production server.